# Django with Amazon S3 via boto3: ImproperlyConfigured

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, boto, boto3

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2014/11/10/Using-Amazon-S3-to-store-your-Django-sites-static-and-media-files/) to set up Amazon S3 with Django.
But as I'm using Python 3.3, I installed a [Python-3 compatible fork](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages) of django-storages and [boto3](https://github.com/boto/boto3) instead.

Here is settings.py file:

```
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ['LIVIN_AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME']
S3_REGION_NAME = os.environ['LIVIN_S3_REGION_NAME']
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ['LIVIN_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ['LIVIN_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']

AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
STATIC_URL = "https://%s/" % AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN

# Tell the staticfiles app to use S3Boto storage when writing the collected
# static files (when you run `collectstatic`).
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
```

When I try, `python manage.py collectstatic` I get this error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'boto'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
...
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not load Boto's S3 bindings.
See https://github.com/boto/boto
```

It seems the storage backend is the boto one, not the boto3 one.

Answer (score 8):

All the configuration is OK, it's just a confusion.
To configure Amazon S3 with Django and Python 3+, I have to use :

- Python 3 compatible django-storages (named django-storages-redux)
- Standard boto package (boto3 has nothing to do with Python actually..)

So, `pip install django-storages-redux, boto` will work like a charm :)

Comment: As mentioned here https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages#history
It seems that the django-storages-redux is now releasing under django-storages, so

`pip install django-storages`
`pip install boto`

worked for me

Comment: Just a note... `boto3` is actually [100% Python](https://github.com/boto/boto3) and is [now compatible](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/issues/57) with `django-storages`.

Answer (score 3):

Django-storages has built in python3 support now. To use django storages with boto3 the following worked for me:

```
pip install boto3
pip install django-storages==1.5.1  --> only version 1.5 and above have boto3 support.
```

use the following staticfiles_storage setting

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

instead of:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
```

Comment: Trying to move from boto to boto3 this did not solve all problems.

Answer (score 1):

I follow to line of code error in file `storages\backends\s3boto.py` and found this error is missing package `google_compute_engine`

[image]

[image]

[image]

Solution: `pip install google_compute_engine` and `collectstatic` again.